# Encryption with RSA Algorithm-letter 'w','x','y','z'

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have been writing code for RSA Algorithm. It works well but, but unfortunately it showed wrong answer for small 'w','z','x','y'.

My encryption algorithm is simple. With two distinct prime number and 'e' I generate the public key, then by generating 'd' I created the private key. Then with the BIGMOD(fast exponentiation) algorithm I just calculate the modulus part to encrypt & decrypt. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

long long int square(long long int a);
long long int BigMod(int M,int E,int N);
void encrypt(int l,int E,int N);
void decrypt(int E,int N );

int main()
{
    main_RSA();
    return 0;
}

void main_RSA()
{

    int p,q;
    printf("Write two distinct Prime number separated by space:");
    scanf("%d %d",&p,&q);
    int n=p*q;
    int phi=(p-1)*(q-1);
    int e;
    printf("Enter a prime number 'e' as GCD(e,(P-1)*(Q-1)) : ");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    printf("public key( e , n ) : ( %d %d )\n",e,n);
    int d,RES=-1;
    for(d=1;;d++){
        RES=(d*e)%phi;
        if(RES==1)break;
    }
    printf("Private Key( d,n ) : ( %d %d )\n",d,n);
    printf("Please input your string : ");
    char arr[1000000];
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(arr);
    int i;
    FILE *fp=fopen("RSAlog.dll","w");
    fclose(fp);
    for(i=0;arr[i];i++){
        int ASCII=arr[i];
        encrypt(ASCII,e,n);
    }
    printf("\n");
    FILE *fpp=fopen("RSAlog.dll","a");
    fprintf(fp,"-1");
    fclose(fpp);
    decrypt(d,n);
}
long long int BigMod(int b,int p,int m)  //b^p%m=?
{
    if(p==0)return 1;
    else if(p%2==0)return square(BigMod(b,p/2,m))%m;
    else return ((b % m) * BigMod(b,p-1,m)) % m;

}

long long int square(long long a)
{
    return a*a;
}

void encrypt(int m ,int e,int n){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("RSAlog.dll","a");
    int c=BigMod(m,e,n);
    printf("%d ",c) ;
    fprintf(fp,"%d ",c);
    fclose(fp);
}

void decrypt(int d,int n){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("RSAlog.dll","r");
    while(1){
        int c;
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&c);
        //printf("%d ",c);
        if(c==-1)break;
        int m=BigMod(c,d,n);
        printf("%c",m);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Write two distinct Prime number separated by space:7 17
Enter a prime number 'e' as GCD(e,(P-1)*(Q-1)) : 5
public key( e , n ) : ( 5 119 )
Private Key( d,n ) : ( 77 119 )
Please input your string : the quick brown fox runs over the lazy dog
114 83 33 2 78 87 56 29 116 2 98 88 76 0 94 2 51 76 1 2 88 87 94 47 2 76 118 33 88 2 114 83 33 2 75 20 5 32 2 53 76 52
the quick bro n fo☺ runs over the la♥☻ dog
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your modulus `m` has to be large enough. To encode and decode all 256 ASCII values, it has to be at least 256.

Since you are using 119 in your example, ASCII code 119 (`'w'`) is treated as 0 et cetera.

Comment: but i don't understand your this line..... "ASCII code 119 ('w') is treated as 0 et cetera."

Comment: @user All calculations for RSA are done modulo `m`. So if `m` is `119`, and the input character you want to encode is also `119`.... `119 % 119 == 0`. That is, the algorithm cannot tell 119 and 0 apart, and analogously for 120 and 1, 121 and 2, etc.

Comment: Oh, i got it.So, to encrypt, the product of pq(=n) is very important. Thanks again for your reply......